# Codeigniter - Upload image, generate thumbnail, save both directories in database

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my model:

I am getting the following error

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Image_lib::data() in C:\xampp\htdocs\adcc\application\models\media_model.php on line 58
```

**My question:** Why can't I use data() to get the ['full_path'] from the saved thumbnail (like I did for upload)?

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

```
public function set_media() {

        $config1 = array(
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
            'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path . '/images',
            'max_size' => 2048
        );

        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->upload->initialize($config1);
        $this->upload->do_upload();

        $image_data = $this->upload->data();

        $config2 = array(
            'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],
            'new_image' => $this->gallery_path . '/thumbs',
            'maintain_ratio' => true,
            'width' => 150,
            'height' => 100
        );

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config2);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        $image_data2 = $this->image_lib->data();

        $this->load->helper('url');

        $id = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);

        $data = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'link' => $this->input->post('link'),
            'year' => $this->input->post('year'),
            'actors' => $this->input->post('actors'),
            'image' => $image_data['full_path'],
            'thumb' => $image_data2['full_path']
        );

        return $this->mongo_db->insert('media', $data);
    }
```

Comment: why you want to generate thumbnail. Uploaded item is image already right? You want pic with smaller size? Check this --> http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the ['full_path'] from data() on the image lib because `$this->image_lib` is not an instance of the upload library and simply doesn't have that method (as the error message states).

With your config now, the image_lib will create the new resized image under the same filename that your original image and save it under the directory you specify in confing's `new_image`. The resulting full path will be saved into the `$full_dst_path` property of the image_lib and there's `$dest_folder` and `$dest_image` for the folder and the filename only too.

So to use these, just drop the line:

```
$image_data2 = $this->image_lib->data(); // delete this line
```

And when saving just write:

```
$data = array(
// ...
'thumb' => $this->image_lib->full_dst_path,
// ...
),
```

Handling the errors that the Upload or Image_lib library could return would be a good idea too.

Answer (score 0):

you need also to initialize the part for the **image_lib** config array before resizing this worked for me     https://stackoverflow.com/a/21187402/2897770

Just add this after loading **image_lib**
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config2);

Answer (score 0):

For file name:

```
$source_image_name = $this->image_lib->source_image;
                    $extension = strrchr($source_image_name , '.');
                    $name = substr($source_image_name , 0, -strlen($extension));                $thumbnail['thumbnail_image_name']$name.$image['thumb_marker'].$extension;
```